Where do the Rust libraries `reqwest` or `hyper` implement (de)serialization of HTTP objects to/from bytes?
I am curious where the Rust libaries reqwest or hyper transform http objects into bytes. reqwest depends on hyper, so one of them must contain this logic. I inspected their documentation and source code, but I found no hint where I can find this logic.
I believe, dispatch.rs or http2.rs are somewhere close, but here I don't see a way to go further. So, could you point me towards the (de)serialization logic of HTTP requests/responses in above-mentioned libraries, i.e., the location where those objects are translated into bytes?
Note, I am aware of some libraries that implement this for HTTP objects, but at this point, I am just curious as to where/how above-mentioned libraries implemented this. So, I don't need library recommendations here.

To confirm: you're asking about both in one question because you expect that it's likely in the same spot due to the dependency, correct?

@RyanM Exactly. request depends on hyper, so one of them (probably hyper) must contain this logic or another dependency that does this. I edited my question to make this clearer.

This question is too broad. The logic is really big, and scattered across at least four crates (and consumes a sizeable part of them).

@ChayimFriedman Really so complicated? Which 4 crates specifically? I think we can take reqwest out because hyper can do this. http contains no serialization logic whatsoever. Then, which other crates are relevant here? I already looked at its dependencies and I have the impression that those aren't relevant to this question.

hyper contains only the basics. Besides reqwest, the logic is also in http-body-util,  tokio-util and possibly more.
